# Super prime numbers. How to generate number with exactly n amount of digits?

Tags: c++, recursion, primes

Recently I have started learning programming on my own and I've come up with this problem I'm struggling with. As an input I have an integer **N** which can be anything from 2 to 9. **N** - is the amount of digits in my final super prime number. According to the problem, super prime number is the number which is prime itself as well when every time I remove the last digit, the remainder must be prime and so on until I got only one digit left. I have to print all super prime numbers, containing the N amount of digits. The problem is that I don't know how to generate a number with exactly N amount of digits.
Here what it says it should be:

```
Input:
7
Output:
2339933 
2399333 
2939999 
3733799 
5939333 
7393913 
7393931 
7393933
```

What I get is 23 and 29 repeated multiple times.
I would be very thankful if someone could help me with this one.

```
void makeNumber(int &num, int&di, int&num1 )
{
    num1=num*10+di;
}
void generatedigit (int &n, int &num, int middle[], int&di, int&num1, int &endlen)
{
for(int j=endlen; j<n;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        di=middle[i];
        makeNumber(num, di,num1);
        if(!isPrime(num1))  {endlen++; generatedigit(n,num,middle,di,num1,endlen); cout<<num1<<endl;}
    }
    }
}

int main(){
  int n,di;
   cin>>n;
   int num,num1,endlen;
   endlen=1;
   int firstnum[4]={2,3,5,7};
   int middle[4]={1,3,7,9};
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       num=firstnum[i];
       generatedigit(n,num,middle,di,num1,endlen);}

   }
```

Comment: Do you know how to generate a number that's exactly one digit?

Comment: Numbers with 7 digits are in the range 1000000 to 9999999.

Comment: To be honest, not really. The best (and the only thing at the moment) I can get is the number of two digits. @DrewDormann

Comment: Just recursively brute force it. Use recursion to loop over the possibilities for the first digit, the second, and so on. Use a simple prime checking algorithm to see if it's prime each time you try adding a digit to the end. Then just think of ways to optimize this and you're good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) I understand that I need to use recursion but the thing is I don't know how to terminate from it. I mean I need to print all possible solutions. When I terminate recursion at the length I want I don't know how to get back to my begging number. Like I need numbers of 3 digits. I stop it when it reaches 3 with if statement and it prints 233. But how can I come back to the number 23 and make it generate 239 for example or how can I come back to number 2 , so it starts generating second number and so it not includes 23? @FeiXiang

Comment: Well, that's one of the problems recursion solves. You can have nested loops with a variable depth. You have a loop in the function looping over possible digits to add to the end, and each time you try a digit, you make a recursive call. After one call prints out a number, it returns to the loop in the caller which loops on to the next number.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it and now finally the program works:) @FeiXiang